# What are some architectural issues you have faced in cloud-focused designs?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, cloud, implementation

When you decided to deploy a cloud setup what are the architectural/implementation issues you have faced and how did you resolve them?

Some examples include:

- (architectural) design patterns when you plan to move your existing application in to cloud
- what non-functional requirements should be give priority?
- how do you overcome the cloud overhead ?  (because of virtualization - like resource metering, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue I faced, were local fallbacks. In a typical cloud scenario you are moving your resources that once lived in a traditional data storage (database, filesystem, etc) to something behind an API, that you can't easily replicate locally. For our application we moved a few typical queues from MySQL to [Amazon's SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/). Problems:

1. Currently Amazon charges $0.01 per 10,000 SQS request, a cost that might seem extremely small, but there's absolutely no reason to pay when developing locally (or for your test server, assuming you have a  separate one).
2. If you don't have a local queue fallback, you need a separate queue per development / testing environment. You really don't want messages from different queues getting mixed up.
3. There isn't a simple way to emulate SQS locally for our environment (that I know of).

Architecturally, I dealt with the transition to SQS with simple [adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern):

- An abstract adapter that did most of the work, with abstract functions for the storage specific stuff,
- A SQS adapter that inherited the abstract adapter, and utilized the SQS SDK,
- A MySQL adapter that was more or less exactly what we had before,
- A [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method) that created Queue models, decided what adapter to use, fed it to the models.

The same architecture (more or less) worked pretty nicely when we moved our images to [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), with a filesystem local fallback. Simple, small and easy enough to explain, and, more importantly, it works. If you are migrating an application to the cloud, chances are you'll be writing quite a few adapters for your back end services, other than having a simple fallback mechanism, you don't want to be vendor locked to a specific service.

Obviously if you are building an application with the cloud in mind, you may not necessarily need local fallbacks, especially if your platform has an easy way of emulating the cloud environment. Something like [Stratosphere](http://stratosphere.codeplex.com/), if you are developing on .Net / Mono or if you are targeting Amazon's services. But if you have a mature application, you already have an infrastructure set up locally, keep using it makes a bit more sense.

The cloud "overhead" is not really something you need to worry about if you are using the cloud as a fancy data store. But if you are looking for cloud computing, then there's no answer, it always depends on what you are doing exactly.

A few relevant questions:

- [What should I do to scale out an high-traffic website?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1280/25936)
- [What are common pitfalls of Cloud Development that you have run into?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/27632/25936)
- [Are there any examples of implementing and effectively responding to a “Chaos Monkey”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/88691/25936)